# QTextEdit and QSyntaxHighlighter save as html

Tags: qt

I have subclassed QTextEdit and QSyntaxHighlighter.

Now I would like to save the formatted document as HTML. toHtml() methods of QTextEdit and QSyntaxHighlighter deliver HTML but they do not include the coloring and other attributes I have in my MySyntaxHighlighter class.

Is there a known why of accessing after-syntax-highlighting HTML data?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this is not possible.